# JMeter - tests report always in XML format even though jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format is set to CSV in all places

Tags: jmeter

I set the correct property to be csv format, but yet my report is still giving me XML. Why would this happen?

When I want to draw the graph with:

```
jmeter -g foo.csv -o graphs
```

I see error:

```
File '/xxx/xxx/foo.csv' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report
An error occurred: Could not read sample <0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the jmx file with Jmeter in GUI mode, select all listeners of results, for example "View results in tree" or "View results in table", and click "Configure" button, check if you have checked the "Save output as XML" and "Save response data" check. Even one listener checks it, the final report will be in XML, even when you set the correct property.

Or, you can open the jmx file in a text editor, search `<responseData>` and `<xml>`. The content of tags should be `false` and `false`, always.

Answer (score 0):

The property needs to be set **before running the test**, not before generating the results.

Also don't use any listeners, they don't add value and just [consume resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean). If you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l foo.csv
```

the `foo.csv` should be in CSV format (assuming default [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config))

If you don't have possibility to re-run the test you can use [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) for converting it from the XML format to CSV format, the Merge Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: Yes, I also tried to set the property, close application, restart, and run again; but at last I found that it's my jmx file which sets it, but I forgot. My fault, of course, but the documentation only mentions the property, but not the checks in the JMX, I believe. The Merge tool is great suggestion.