# Jmeter decompress gzip response

Tags: jmeter, gzip, gzipinputstream

I write performance test script with JMeter, but the target site using gzip to compress response. So Jmeter can't display any response and only show EOFException.

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:269)
```

To solve this problem. I write JSR223 PostProcessor for decompress response, but my script always show "Not in GZIP format" message.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
```

I don't have any idea about this message. Please help me.

This is my "JSR223 PostProcessor" script.

```
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

byte[] responseBody = prev.getResponseData();
ByteArrayOutputStream decompressBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try(InputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody))) {
    int b;
    while ((b = gzip.read()) != -1) {
        decompressBaos.write(b);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    log.info("Exception:"+ex);
}

byte[] decompressed = decompressBaos.toByteArray();
prev.setResponseData(decompressed);
```

[image: response header]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the response is in GZIP format? In order to be able to request it in GZIP you need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682981/jmeter-tests-report-always-in-xml-format-even-though-jmeter-save-saveservice-o/70683804#70683804) and configure it to send [`Accept-Encoding` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) with the value of `gzip,deflate`

Comment: I'm sorry, the real problem is that target site uses Transfer-Encoding: chunked.
I assumed it was a GZIP problem.　This issue will be closed.